# ScrollingGraphicalViewer Select and Unselect listener

Tags: eclipse-gef

I need to fire a method when a figure is selected in GEF diagram.
addSelectionChangedListener works well when I select a figure, but if i click on the same figure again ("unselect") the listener doesn't fire.

How can i fix it?

```
final GraphicalViewer viewer = new ScrollingGraphicalViewer();
viewer.addSelectionChangedListener(new ISelectionChangedListener() {
     public void selectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent event) {
    //Fired when figure is selected, but not when same figure is selected again

     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can implement a toggling behaviour for a GEF figure through the selection mechanism. The `selectionChanged` event gets fired when the selection **changes**, so clicking twice on the same figure is not going to make it.

Maybe a different approach is needed taking into consideration that a figure is deselected when another figure gets selected and that you can retrieve the that element from the `SelectionChangedEvent` object passed in.

Also, you should only care about the user selecting a figure within the diagram and not a different element from any other workbench part.